# Upgrading to latest version of Git

Tags: macos, git, github

Trying to upgrade to the latest version of Git. because I get the message  "Your version of git is 1.8.5.2. Which has serious security vulnerabilities" I have upgraded via homebrew but it still showing the old version not the new version 2.4.1. Ran the following commands (using osx yosemite version 10.10.1)

**brew update**

```
Updated Homebrew from 6cb91e45 to bc541b9d.
==> New Formulae
apache-drill           gumbo-parser           mlogger
blockhash          hebcal             moe
```

==> Deleted Formulae
datamash    git-latexdiff   shell.fm    texwrapper
dupx        lilypond    sslscan

**brew install git**

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/git-2.4.1.yosemite.bottle.t
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring git-2.4.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The "contrib" directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.1: 1370 files, 31M
```

but when i do git --version it gives me git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48). However brew upgrade git gives me

Error: git 2.4.1 already installed

the command **which git** gives me 
/usr/local/bin/git

how can i access the latest version of Git?

Comment: If `which git` shows git pointing to the homebrew installation site it seems to me it should be trumping apple's installed one. Have you tried moving apple's git installation? `sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple`

Comment: hi sorry - just need restarting now getting  2.4.1!

Answer (score 0):

just needed restarting now getting  2.4.1!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Vatine Did you happen to notice that this is the original questioner answering his own question? Granted, it could probably be worded better, but if it resolved the issue he/she was having, then it does "provide an answer to the question"...

Comment: @twalberg No, I didn't. However, it still looks more commentary than an actual answer.